# Do celebrities have their body parts insured?

Tags: celebrities

I have read some articles listing celebrities that have their legs, butts etc. insured.

Is that true or just some PR statements about "million dollars worth body"?

If it's true, it would be interesting to know how can someone get their arbitrary asset insured and what are the policies? What has to happen, to get the insurance? Will Daniel Craig gets money for his insured body if he gets a scratch on his hand? Or his entire body has to fall off?

Comment: http://www.propertycasualty360.com/2015/03/19/they-insured-what-10-celebrities-and-their-lucrati

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. [Here](http://www.mtv.com/news/2106332/celebrity-body-part-insurance-taylor-swift/) is an interview with a representative of an insurance company that provides these policies.

> a celeb (or their agent) goes to a broker who helps them figure out the whole insurance situation. They’ll have to talk about what body part the celeb wants insured, ideally for how much, and if she wants it just for an event (e.g. VMAs, Grammys) — or forever.

[Here](http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/explainer/2006/06/does_the_explainer_have_billiondollar_legs.html) is a primer from Slate:

> ... it's pretty easy to get disability insurance from standard insurers in the United States. To get insurance for a particular body part, though, you'll probably need to turn to the "surplus lines" market, which covers all the oddball risks that the regular companies don't handle.
>
> [...]
>
> Lloyd's of London has provided some of the most famous celebrity body-part policies, like those for Jimmy Durante's $50,000 nose, Bette Davis' $28,000 waistline, and Michael Flatley's $39 million legs.

[Lloyds](https://www.lloyds.com/lloyds/about-us/history/innovation-and-unusual-risks/going-out-on-a-limb) describes their history of insuring celebrity body parts.

Comment: Doesn't everybody though? Health insurance is a thing here... (Of course, the values are tabulated, but still)

Comment: @JanDvorak These policies explicitly set aside particular body parts and insure them at values well above what can obtained through typical health insurance. I added more of the Slate article to make that clear.

Comment: @JanDvorak Health insurances are usually there to cover medical costs, not to pay the holder a pre-agreed sum of money in case body parts are injured or lost. It is rather a kind of inability-to-work insurance for artists, musicians, actors, models, athletes and other persons depending on specific body parts to do their work.